# Is it possible to run QNX neutrino RTOS with native/full virtualization on microkernal based VMM?

Tags: qnx, hypervisor, qnx-neutrino

Is it possible to run QNX neutrino RTOS with native/full virtualization on microkernal based VMM (like CodeZero, Sel4, 
PikOS)?

---

I read Linux and android support full virtualization and it is possible to run them on any VM without modifying 
the kernel. Does the same possible with QNX? or QNX only supports para virtualization?

---

Is there any  reference 
documentation on QNX virtualization?

---

I knew QNX provides its own hypervisor. But i am trying on other hypervisors.

---

I am new to both QNX and virtualization. I apologize if the question is not properly framed or unclear. In that case, do mention in comments.

Comment: Try posting in QNX forum also: http://community.qnx.com/sf/go/projects.core_os/discussion

Comment: @H.Ilyas I did. Waiting for a reply.